# How to append line to inactive window buffer and scroll that window to bottom

Tags: vim

I want to develop a vim plugin that writes some lines to inactive window(some window for async command output etc.)

I know I can use "setbufline" to write to buffer, and use redraw to draw the vim screen.  but I can't find a function to scroll specific window to bottom.  Is there a function like "cbottom" but works for normal window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the windowId of the window to scroll and you stored it in the variable `g:scrollWinId`:

```
let curWinId = win_getid()
call win_gotoid(g:scrollWinId)
normal! G
call win_gotoid(curWinId)
```

I'm not aware that there is a simple function in Vim script or a autocmd that could be used.

BTW: You might want to use `appendbufline` instead of `setbufline`.

Comment: It would be slightly more reliable to use `normal! G` instead. If somebody maps `G` to something different in their own vimrc, `normal!` will use the built-in.

Comment: @AndrewRadev Updated.